# Android Intent-Filter Priority

Tags: android, android-intent

Android applications can specify intent-priority. How does android handle security situation such as following. An application 'Apple' as SMS_RECEIVED intent-priority to be 1000, and application 'Orange' as SMS_RECEIVED intent-priority to be 1100. Obviously, Orange will handle intent first, and then Apple. But what would happen if Orange aborts the broadcast by calling 'abortBroadcast()' ? 'Apple' would never get a chance to handle the SMS. Does android provide any security to prevent such a thing ? or Is there any work around ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common behavior only in case of ordered broadcasts. Only broadcasts that are started using `sendOrderedBroadcast`  are sent only to one receiver at time. And you can then in this receiver abort the broadcast. You can read [this](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~afelt/android_permissions.pdf) article to clarify the situation.

Comment: Thanks Yury for the white paper. However, my question is still not answered. As one developer or entity can easily counter attack other by having higher priority intents and aborting it.